# Error en modal de Boostrap con JSP y Servlets

Tags: javascript, ajax, bootstrap, jsp, servlets

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con JSP, Servlets y Bootstrap, pero tengo un problema al momento de mostrar un modal el problema consiste en que imprimo en una tabla datos traidos desde la base de datos y ahi tengo las opciones de eliminar y editar, cuando se le de editar quiero que aparezca un modal con los datos del registro, pero no consigo hacerlo he intentado de muchas maneras pero de ninguna manera he podido resolver el problema.

En el siguiente código imprimo los valores traidos de la consulta:

```html
while (rs.next()) {
   String clave = rs.getString("clave");
   String nombre = rs.getString("nombre");
   String ubicacion = rs.getString("ubicacion");
   String telefono = rs.getString("telefono");

   out.println("<tr class='info'>");

   out.println("<td>");

   out.println(clave);

   out.println("</td><td>");

   out.println(nombre);

   out.println("</td><td>");

   out.println(ubicacion);

   out.println("</td><td>");

   out.println(telefono);

   out.println("</td><td>");

   out.println("<button class='btn btn-danger' onclick='confirmarDelete("
     + clave + ")'>Eliminar</button>");
   out.println("</td>");

   out.println("<td>");
   
   out.println("<button onclick='showModalEdit("+ clave + ")' class='btn btn-success'>Editar</button>");
   out.println("</td>");

   out.println("</tr>");

  }
```

En el botón `<button onclick='showModalEdit("+ clave + ")' class='btn btn-success'>Editar</button>` llamo a una función de JavaScript la cual recibe como parámetro el cádigo(llave primaria) e intento mandar a llamar mediante AJAX a un servlet:

Codigo JavaScript:

```js
function showModalEdit(clave){
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
     url: "buscar",
        contentType: "application/json", // NOT dataType!
        data: JSON.stringify(clave),
       success: function(responseJson) {
         $.each(responseJson, function(index, item) {  
                document.getElementById(item+"Edit").value = item;
            });
  
   document.getElementById("claveEdit").value = clave;

    document.getElementById("tituloEdit").innerHTML = "Editar "+clave;
   $('#modalEdit').modal('show'); 
   
  }
```

Servlet:

```html
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Conexion conexion = new Conexion();
  String clave = request.getParameter("clave");
  Statement Estamento;
  String nombre = "";
  String telefono = "";
  String ubicacion = "";
  try {
   Estamento = conexion.conectarBD().createStatement();
   ResultSet rs = Estamento.executeQuery("select clave, nombre, ubicacion, telefono from delegacion where clave = "+clave);
   while(rs.next()){
    nombre = rs.getString("nombre");
    telefono = rs.getString("telefono");
    ubicacion = rs.getString("ubicacion");
   }
   List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
      list.add(nombre);
      list.add(ubicacion);
      list.add(telefono);
      String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
      response.setContentType("application/json");
      response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
      response.getWriter().write(json);
      
  } catch (SQLException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Pero no me trae nada de la ejecucion. También lo intente pasando los valores como parámetros de JavaScript pero tampoco me funciona:

Código del botón: `out.println("<button onclick='showModalEdit("+ clave + ","+ nombre + ","+ ubicacion + ","+ telefono + ")' class='btn btn-success'>Editar</button>");`

Funcion de JavaScript:

```js
function showModalEdit(clave, nombre, ubicacion, telefono){
  document.getElementById("claveEdit").value = clave;
    document.getElementById("nombreEdit").value = nombre;
    document.getElementById("ubicacionEdit").value = ubicacion;
    document.getElementById("telefonoEdit").value = telefono;
    document.getElementById("tituloEdit").innerHTML = "Editar "+clave;
   $('#modalEdit').modal('show'); 
   
  }
```

Cédigo del modal:

```html
<!-- Modal editar-->
 <div class="modal fade" id="modalEdit" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <!-- Modal content-->
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
     <h4 class="modal-title" id="tituloEdit"></h4>
    </div>
    <form id="formEditar" method="POST" action="edit">
    <div class="modal-body">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="clave">Clave</label> <input type="text"
       class="form-control" id="claveEdit" name="clave" 
       readonly>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label> <input type="text"
       class="form-control" id="nombreEdit" name="nombre"
       >
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ubicacion">Ubicación:</label> <input type="text"
       class="form-control" id="ubicacionEdit" name="ubicacion"
       >
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="telefono">Telefono:</label> <input type="text"
       class="form-control" id="telefonoEdit" name="telefono"
       >
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Editar</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
     </div>
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Lo mejor es que primero busques donde específicamente esta el error, ya que estas mostrandonos un monton de codigo y debes acotarlo a lo que exactamente no funciona. Para esto utiliza firefox o chrome y herramientas de desarrolladores y fijate en si la funcion ajax esta funcionando y que es lo que devuelve, esto lo puedes hacer en las funciones de red de chrome. Tambien debes fijarte si es que la ejecucion tuvo errores y esto lo puedes ver en la pestaña consola del navegador.

Comment: Me marca el siguiente error en la consola: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` en la linea `<button onclick='showModalEdit(8964,Hospital,Cosamaloapan,789654)' class='btn btn-success'>Editar</button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al generar el onclick del elemento button estas enviando los string sin comillas:

```html
<button onclick='showModalEdit(8964,Hospital,Cosamaloapan,789654)' class='btn btn-success'>Editar</button>
```

Por lo tanto el script no se llega a ejecutar por que esta esperando la funcion o variable Hospital.

Al generar el boton preocupate de que se genere con las comillas correspondientes:

```
out.println("<button onclick='showModalEdit(\""+ clave + "\",\""+ nombre + "\",\""+ ubicacion + "\",\""+ telefono + "\")' class='btn btn-success'>Editar</button>");
```

Saludos!

Comment: Despues de mucho tiempo de buscar era lo que estaba mal las comillas, me sirvio mucho el codigo. Saludos